# CharSequence или String?

Tags: java, android, строки

Подскажите, в чем принципиальное отличие между этими объектами? В каких случаях оптимально использовать CharSequence?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

CharSequence это интерфейс со всеми вытекающими. Под капотом может быть CharBuffer, Segment, String, StringBuffer, StringBuilder. Или собственная реализация.

Чтобы было понимание приведу следующий пример:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = new String("Hello from String");
        soutString(str);
    }

    public static void soutString(String str) {
        System.out.println(str.getClass());
        System.out.println(str);
   }
}
```

Метод `SoutString` выводит класс и содержимое строки:

```
class java.lang.String
Hello from String
```

Если мы захотим использовать `StringBuilder`, то для того что бы воспользоваться методом `SoutString` мы должны использовать преобразование. Так как он ожидает `String`:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Hello from StringBuilder");
soutString(sb.toString());
```

Добавляем эти строки и смотрим результат:

```
class java.lang.String
Hello from String
class java.lang.String
Hello from StringBuilder
```

Мы так же знаем, что `String` и `StringBuilder` реализуют интерфейс 'CharSequence' и это позволяет нам написать следующее:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CharSequence str = new String("Hello from String");
        soutCharSequence(str);
        CharSequence sb = new StringBuilder("Hello from StringBuilder");
        soutCharSequence(sb);
    }

    public static void soutCharSequence(CharSequence ch) {
        System.out.println(ch.getClass());
        System.out.println(ch);
   }
}
```

Вывод будет следующим:

```
class java.lang.String
Hello from String
class java.lang.StringBuilder
Hello from StringBuilder
```

Отметим тот факт, что во втором случае в метод был передан `StringBuilder`.

- Мы можем передавать в наш метод любые классы, которые реализуют интерфейс.
- Внутри метода можно использовать методы интерфейса, например length();

А еще мы можем внутри метода безопасно выполнить специфические для объекта действия:

```
     if (ch instanceof String) {
        System.out.println(((String) ch).toUpperCase());
     }
```

Я не знаток Android, но думаю, что @Barmaley хотел сказать что если передается в качестве `CharSequence` объект `String`, то будет выводится просто текст. А если объект дополнительно реализует `Spannable`, то его еще можно и раскрасить.

Answer (score 5):

Формально конечно `CharSequence` это интерфейс, но смысловая нагрузка `CharSequence` в Android обычно предполагает, что набор символов может иметь в дальнейшем некие стили - конкретно `Spannable`, ну например, можно сделать чтобы часть строки имел другой цвет или шрифт.

Соответственно `CharSequence` имеет смысл использовать, если предполагается, что частям строки нужно/можно придавать определенные специальные свойства - то есть то чего нельзя добиться лобовым использованием `String`.

Comment: Внезапно `Spannable` тоже интерфейс.

Comment: @SergeyMitrofanov и что дальше то? Если вы из разряда грамма-наци с Java уклоном так и скажите :)

Answer (score 1):

`CharSequence` - это любой набор символов, не обязательно иммутабельный, как объект String. В этом интерфейсе определено буквально 4 метода. В android его реализуют как различные строки и их билдеры (String, StringBuilder, и т.п.), так и текст с форматированием (`Spanned`).

Любой `CharSequence` можно преобразовать в строку методом `.toString()`, но это может быть преобразование с потерей информации. Например, если преобразовать в строку текст с форматированием (`Spanned`), то из него удалится всё форматирование, а если преобразовать StringBuilder, то потеряется возможность редактирования этой строки. Кроме того, такое преобразование — это почти всегда создание нового объекта.

Использовать лучше везде, где достаточно 4 методов интерфейса `CharSequence` и не нужны возможности класса String, либо нужно сохранить свойства переданного объекта при передаче куда-то дальше. Но нужно быть осторожным. В частности, лучше не использовать метод `equals()` для сравнения объектов, так как он может быть не определен, либо определен не так, как вы хотели бы.